# Theta lies in which quadrant?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin \theta = -\frac{\sqrt 3}2 $and $\tan \theta = \sqrt 3$, then theta lies in which quadrant?

I guess $\sin \theta$ is in the $IV$ quadrant and $\tan \theta$ is in the $III$ quadrant. But I didn't understand further part? Please let me know.

Comment: You  have one angle $\theta$ with $\sin\theta<0$. This tells you $\theta$ is either in Q4 or Q3. Now use the information on $\tan\theta$ to find in which of these two quadrants $\theta$ lies.

Comment: $\sin\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are numbers. They don't lie in a quadrant. They do, however, tell you something about which quadrant the angle $\theta$ is in.

Comment: You need to remember "All Strippers Take Cash".  All major trig functions are positive in I, only sine in II, only tangent in III, and only cosine in IV.

Answer (score 5):

Your $\sin\theta$ is negative, which means III or IV quadrant. Your $\tan\theta$ is positive. Since $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, it means that $\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{2}$ - negative. Thus $\theta$ is in III quadrant

Comment: More simply, if $\tan\theta>0$, $\theta$ is in the first or third quadrant ($\tan\theta$ is obtained with a central projection).